# File upload fails when using ajax submit with return false

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that has a simple file input.

```
<form id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" action="addFile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="uploadWUID" id="uploadWUID">
    <p>Please upload a signed and completed write-up in PDF format.  Please file the hardcopy of the write-up per company policy.</p>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:7px;">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                Browse&hellip; <input type="file" id="reportImport" name="reportImport">
            </span>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
</form>
```

There is some local javascript that puts the filename in the text input, but the text input is not used in the PHP file.

The uploadWUID is set dynamically and is passed to add the uploaded file to a specific record in a database.

When I submit the form it works just fine.  My browser redirects to addFile.php, success is echoed out, the file is moved to the correct directory and the database is updated.

My issues comes when I add return false to my ajax form submission. I get an error back from the php file stating it couldn't find the index when processing $filename = $_FILES['reportImport']['name']; and my upload/database update fails.

```
$('#uploadFile').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        success: function(response) {}
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: notice that javascript is executed synchronously - try to return your `false` value inside of the success handler: `success: function(response){ return false }`

Comment: Is that need return false

Comment: @messerbill, that allows the form to submit correctly but doesn't stop the page from directing to the addFile.php page.  I need the return false to keep from redirecting the browser.  Want to stay on my current page.

Comment: so don't use `submit` but a simple ajax call after clicking a button. You do not need to submit forms to send data to the server since you use `ajax` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change script code**

```
$('#uploadFile').submit(function() {
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);              
        $.ajax({
          data: formData,
          type: $(this).attr('method'),
          url: $(this).attr('action'),
          processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
          contentType: false,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
          success: function(response) {
             console.log(response);
             alert(response);
             return false
          }
        });
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you very much.  My question now is why?  Is it the processData and contentType, that I was missing with my call?

Comment: @Pieter It’s imperative that you set the contentType option to false, forcing jQuery not to add a Content-Type header for you, otherwise, the boundary string will be missing from it. Also, you must leave the processData flag set to false, otherwise, jQuery will try to convert your FormData into a string, which will fail.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, makes sense.  I couldn't for the life of me understand why it would complete as along as I wasn't trying to stay on my current page.